# Invalid option file options: pad=oper

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, command-line-arguments, astyle

Getting this error: Invalid option file options on trying to invoke Astyle via C#

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Astyle.exe";

    //strCommandParameters are parameters to pass to program
    //pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--style=ansi --recursive  "+System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)+"/*.cpp";

    pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " options=none test.cpp";
    //pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " -h";
    pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    //Set output of program to be written to process output stream
    pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    //Optional
    pProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    //Start the process
    pProcess.Start();

    //Get program output
    string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string strError = pProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    //Wait for process to finish
    pProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [this link](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Options) the correct syntax seems to be

```
--options=none
```

Comment: +1 for digging through documentation even without a link provided.

Comment: @kingpin: remember you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved (or helped to solve) your problem